# How do I PIVOT two values of different data types from a row to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following SQL to pivot 1. a text value and 2. a date value
but return the Microsoft SQL Server error of

> Msg 8624, Level 16, State 17, Line 1
>
> Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce
>   a query plan. For more information, contact Customer Support Services.

Any help?

```
    SELECT
  occurrence,KeyObject,KeyNumb,ProcessStartDate,Reference,ProcessNo,
  [forename] AS Forename, [surname] AS Surname, [TenLetDate] as TenLetDate
FROM
(SELECT  
LGOVProcessData.ProcessNo
  ,LGOVProcessData.occurrence
  ,LGOVProcessDataItems.FieldName AS Fieldname
  ,LGOVProcessDataItems.FieldName AS Fieldname2
  ,LGOVProcessDataItems.strValue
  ,LGOVProcessDataItems.dateValue
  ,LGOVProcessData.DataID
  ,W2Process.KeyObject
  ,W2Process.KeyNumb
  ,W2Process.ProcessNo AS 'W2ProcessProcessNo'
  ,W2Process.ProcessStartDate
  ,W2Process.Reference
FROM
  LGOVProcessData
  INNER JOIN LGOVProcessDataItems
    ON LGOVProcessData.DataID = LGOVProcessDataItems.DataID
  INNER JOIN W2Process
    ON LGOVProcessData.ProcessNo = W2Process.ProcessNo
WHERE
  LGOVProcessData.TemplateID = 5299
 ) ps
  PIVOT 
  (
  MAX(strValue) 
  FOR 
  FieldName IN 
  ([forename], [surname]
  ) as pvt
    PIVOT 
  (
  MAX(dateValue) 
  FOR 
  FieldName2 IN 
  ([TenLetDate])
  ) as pvt
```

[image: Data and desired outcome]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: read about *conditional aggregation*...

Comment: I would recommend sample data and desired results.